# Multiple entries in AD for same printer name on same server with cnames?

Tags: active-directory, printing

I have been asked to replicate a client's AD/server/printer environment. They have sent me some fairly limited information and I am unable to get any more easily. They have sent a screenshot showing that they have identical pairs of printer names listed (in AD) on their main print server. They also mentioned something about CNAMES.

I am struggling to replicate this environment, even playing with CNAMES. I can't figure out how you would get two printer names (i.e. queues) with the same name on the same server, everything I do (except low-level editing of AD with ADSIEdit) windows prevents duplicate printer names. (I'm using Server 2003) Can anyone tell me, first, why would someone do such a thing!! (Particularly because they sometimes have different models listed under the same printer name) and secondly how I replicate the environment?

many thanks Mark p.s. be gentle I'm a printer man, not an AD man!

Comment: If it is permissible, posting the screenshot would help us understand this... interesting environment.

Comment: We use the same printer several times to set different settings/permissions.. for instance, most users can print in b&w, whereas only a few can print in colour.. but the exact same name?

Comment: Yup /exactly/ the same printer name. Have put a jpg with the name of the client scrubbed out here: http://irishmark.co.uk/screengrab.jpg

You can see they even have different physical printers with the same name on the same server.

Comment: I'm with you Mark, I can't see how this is possible. Your printer server is going to let you know if you have printers with exactly the same name, shared or otherwise, so I am wondering if there may be a glitch in Active Directory that is causing the queues to be published twice, or whether something special has been done to their AD Environment.